# How to resolved screen cut issue when app minimize and keyboard close

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, keyboard

I have used chat custom editor and when keyboard is open and then if we minimize app then screen layout cut as show in image please give me some solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Hi didn't understood the problem. Is it not showing keyboard when open after minimize? Is it the problem?

Comment: @Anand please check update image

Comment: Is the editor is focuses? Can your minimal xaml?

Comment: @Anand minimal xaml means?

Comment: I mean  relevent code. You can share the xaml of you chat page

Comment: and also try every windowSoftInputMode

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/177332/white-screen-when-closing-android-keyboard

Comment: yes I have tried all windowSoftInputMode.